# Yarn build failed with Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, antd

I was going to redeploy a web app, so I was trying to run yarn build, and it runs into this error.

I am using Ant Design, I also did a yarn eject before, after a search through google still no luck, any encountered this is an error before? Any tips on solving it? thanks!

```
yarn run v1.22.0
$ react-app-rewired build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/antd/es/style/index.less
TypeError: this[MODULE_TYPE] is not a function


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: I am trying to solve the same issue from a long time. but still unable to catch and solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I faced the same issue. My problem was I mixed up with Ant Design versions. Ant v4.x was released recently, so I used components without checking the version. So, try using components of same version and see if it works!!.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for anyone who might face the same issue, you need to remove **react-rewire** and do the migration from V3 to V4 shown on Ant.Design Doc, then should be fine